# require ngModel syntax in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I see the following:

```
// my-directive.js    
return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    ngModel: '=',
  },
  controller: controller,
  link: myLink
};

// my-link.js
return function(scope, $element, attrs, modelController) {
  scope.onMyClick = function(event) {
    modelController.$setViewValue(getItem(event));
  }
};

// foo.html
<my-directive ng-model="myModel"></my-directive>
```

Is the `ng-model` directive used to provide a two way data-binding to the `myModel` in the outer scope where the `my-directive` instance is declared?

Is this the idiomatic way to provide two-way data binding between a directive and an outer model in Angular 1.4?

Does the `require: 'ngModel'` in the directive definition do anything other than inject the controller instance for the `ng-model` directive instance into the link function `my-link`?

Finally, does it make the controller of `ng-model` available on the scope for the controller of `my-directive` to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different things here - `ng-model` as directive and `ngModel: '='` in directive as attribute. Lets split them:

```
<my-directive ng-model="myModel" whatever="myModel"></my-directive>

return {
  require: 'ngModel',
  scope: {
    myModel: '=',
  },
  controller: controller,
  link: myLink
};
```

> Is the ng-model directive used to provide a two way data-binding to
>   the myModel in the outer scope where the my-directive instance is
>   declared?

No, 2-way binding is provided by definition inside directive. (`whatever` here)

> Is this the idiomatic way to provide two-way data binding between a
>   directive and an outer model in Angular 1.4?

One you used scope : `{ whatever : '='}` is usual way.

> Does the require: 'ngModel' in the directive definition do anything
>   other than inject the controller instance for the ng-model directive
>   instance into the link function my-link

Not that much, if u use directive without ngModel it will throw error.

> Finally, does it make the controller of ng-model available on the
>   scope for the controller of my-directive to use?

No, it doesnt add anything to your scope. You just can access injected controller.